# How to make some part of text bold in SAPUI5

Tags: json, sapui5

I want to display some portion of text bold in `sapui5` application.

For example,

> **Welcome** User,

view:

```
Text id="t" text="Welcome"
```

Controller:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("model/data.json","",false);
var data = oModel.getProperty("/cricketers/0/name");
var text= sap.ui.getCore().byId("t");
$("#t").prepend('"'+"<b>"+data+"</b>"+'"');
```

I tried this method but it couldn't help me. Could anybody please help me?

Comment: Take a look at https://answers.sap.com/answers/13174954/view.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for [sap.m.FormattedText](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.FormattedText.html), here is the [sap.m.FormattedText explored example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText/preview) (click the code button there to see the code).

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet shows, how to do it. It uses [sap.m.FormattedText](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.FormattedText). I adapted the [demokit documentation example](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.FormattedText/sample/sap.m.sample.FormattedText)
to you use case:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
  onInit: function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModel.setData({
      HTML: "Welcome <strong>User</strong>"
    });

    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
  }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
  })
  .placeAt("uiArea");
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="view1.initial" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <VBox class="sapUiMediumMargin">
      <FormattedText htmlText="{/HTML}" />
    </VBox>

  </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to make a piece of text fully bold, you could use a Label with design="Bold".

```js
    sap.ui.controller("view.labelExample", {
      onInit: function(oEvent) {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({
          username: "User"
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        this.getView().byId("needsspace").addStyleClass("spaceText");
      }
    });

    sap.ui.xmlview(
      "main", {
        viewContent: jQuery("#view").html()
      }
    ).placeAt("uiArea");
```

```css
.spaceText{
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

    <div id="uiArea"></div>

    <script id="view" type="ui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View controllerName="view.labelExample" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
        <HBox class="sapUiMediumMargin">
          <Label id="needsspace" text="Welcome"/><Label text="{/username}" design="Bold"/>
        </HBox>

      </mvc:View>
    </script>
```